# Query Database inside a loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have multiple dropdown menus. When the user clicks submit button. The isset function in the if clause is triggerd and the following code gets executed

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
     $player_id = $_REQUEST['players'];
     var_dump ($player_id);
            for($i=0; $i < sizeof($player_id); $i++) //query database with different player_id each time
            {
                foreach ($player_id as $id){
                    $query = 'SELECT `name`  FROM `player_info`
                    WHERE `player_id` = '.$id;
                    $return_names = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                                            }
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($return_names))
                        {
                            $selected[] = $row['name'];     
                        }                   
                        var_dump($selected);
                    }
                }
```

What the above code should do is return the names, of the players, the user selected. However when I open it I get this:

[image]

Notice the $player_id array which I use in the 1st var_dump holds the different player_id values.

However when I do a var_dump on the second array $selected the array contains only the values "Burger"

I suspect the problem is in the foreach loop and the way I query the database. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do u use both `for` and `foreach` loop?

Comment: I would like to mention that this script is very vulnerable for an SQL-injection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `for($i=0; $i < sizeof($player_id); $i++)` is an excessive loop. You are not using `$i` from this loop so you need not it. Just imagine, if your $player_id array has 3 items, you will loop it, and on every step of this looping, you also will loop whole $player_id array one more time by using `foreach` loop.

Also, you are using unsafe method to pass variables in the query. Best practice I think is acquire a habit to convert income $_POST variables to `int` if they are suggested be numbers. It's just one string `$player_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['players']);`, or `$id = (int)$_POST['id']`, or `$number = (int)$_GET['number']`, etc.

Another thing is overquering your database. Instead of creating separate query for every ID, you can use one query with `IN` operator, which right side is all IDs joined by commas.

Another safe variant of your code is:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $player_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['players']);

    //var_dump($player_ids);

    $query = 'SELECT `name` 
        FROM `player_info` 
        WHERE `player_id` IN (' . implode(',', $player_ids) . ')';

    $return_names = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($return_names) ) {
        $selected[] = $row['name'];
    }

    //var_dump($selected);
}
```

Comment: Best practice would be to use *placeholders*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I've added one vote for your answer for using placeholders. But *native* PHP does not give a chance to use placeholders. :)

Also, I would rewrite your answer as: `$names = $db->getCol('SELECT name  FROM player_info WHERE player_id in (?a)', $_POST['players']);`. This variant will use even more force. ))))

Comment: Surely native PHP allow placeholders, even with old mysql ext. User-defined functions are no less *native*. One-line variant would be *less readable* - this is why it should be avoided.

Comment: I just clown about one-string variant, never mind. My variant is with `$query = '....'` too. )))

Answer (score 2):

Use the Force, Luke!
With abstraction library like [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) it will be *two* lines of code

```
$sql = 'SELECT name  FROM player_info WHERE player_id in (?a)';
$names = $db->getCol($sql,$_POST['players']);
```

And, unlike yours - it is *safe* from injection.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `for` loop and it should work. You want to iterate over each player id, which you are doing using `foreach`. The `for` outside it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially running the same loop twice.  Take out

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($player_id); $i++){}
```

Answer (score -1):

You' re double-looping for no reason.

Also, while you execute one `SELECT` for each player id, you're trying to iterate the result outside `foreach`, which means that you end up iterating only the last one.

Moreover, none of your `SELECT`s need iteration, provided that they produce at most one row.

Try it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  $player_id = $_REQUEST['players'];
  var_dump ($player_id);
  foreach ($player_id as $id)
    {
    $query = 'SELECT `name`  FROM `player_info` WHERE `player_id` = '.$id;
    $return_names = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($return_names); // at most one -- or not?
    if($row)
      {
      $selected=$row['name'];     
      var_dump($selected);
      }
    else
      echo "Player with id $id not found in DB!";
    }
  }
```